# Can game designers or developers be addicted to online games?

Tags: game-design

Do game designers/developers play as much as hardcore gamers, and could they be considered addicted? In the clinical addiction sense. If yes, is it good or bad? If not, is it called enthusiasm?

I'm asking to know how developers / designers feel about the question is video game addiction.

Comment: I am not sure this is constructive... or a good fit for this site, for what it's worth.

Comment: So hardcore gamer = addicted? Would you say a cinephile is addicted to movies? Or a philosopher to reading books?

Comment: This is really a psychology/sociology/medical question, not a game design question.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Hardcore gamers and game developers, of course! As with many aspects in life, there's some overlap. See above. (note, the center area does not mean they develop hardcore games, it means *they are hardcore*.)

The latter part of your question is discouraging. Faith in humanity discouraging. **Clinical addiction of any kind is bad**. You seem to think it's some kind of joke. It's not. Even though you're talking about games. [Addictions to computer games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_addiction), like addictions to other things, tears families apart and ruins people's lives. Would you call that enthusiasm? Nope.

Comment: I would think the intersection area is much bigger

Comment: +1 for "Clinical addiction of any kind is bad."  I mean, duh.

Comment: I'd say the more truly addicted to games someone is, the less time they have to develop them.

Comment: Lol'd hard, don't know what is funnier, this answer or the question.